# Why is owssvr.dll causing a 404 error code?

Tags: 2010, 404

In my SP 2010 webapp web.config file I have custom 404 error handling enabled via httpErrors:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
   <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_layouts/somepath/customerrors/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
 </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

And this works fine except when trying to do something such as delete a related list item which would normally return a standard SP error message. However with the above custom error handling implemented, instead of the usual error message SP the custom 404 page is returned. On inspecting the requests in chrome debugger I can see that the culprit is owssvr.dll
e.g

```
http://devsomedomain:1000/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&Cmd=Delete&List={926EA17B-9A35-4FDB-9C9A-A8681528C08B}&ID=1&NextUsing=http%3A%2F%2Fdevbld139%3A1000%2FLists%2FFacilities%2FAllItems%2Easpx%3FInitialTabId%3DRibbon%252EListItem%26VisibilityContext%3DWSSTabPersistence&ContentTypeId=0x0100C4F6B103004A974AA690BA30CFEAA8B1
```

So why does this occur and can I prevent this and still use my custom 404 error handling?
Thanks.